# XSLT split XML into groups based on Matching condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I am stuck at a point in XSLT:
My xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<nums>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

My Current XSLT is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pGroupSize" select="3"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <nums>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
       "num[position() mod $pGroupSize = 1]"/>
  </nums>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num">
  <group>
   <xsl:copy-of select=
    ".|following-sibling::*
              [not(position() > $pGroupSize -1)]"/>
  </group>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My current Output:
Splits the xml irrespective of node value.

```
<nums>
   <group>
      <num>02</num>
      <num>02</num>
      <num>03</num>
   </group>
   <group>
      <num>04</num>
      <num>05</num>
      <num>06</num>
   </group>
   <group>
      <num>07</num>
      <num>08</num>
      <num>09</num>
   </group>
   <group>
      <num>10</num>
   </group>
</nums>
```

My expected output XML:
First checks if there are any matching node to last node, If yes include them, else exclude them.

```
<nums>
   <group>
      <num>02</num>
      <num>02</num>
      <num>03</num>
   </group>
   <group>
      <num>04</num>
      <num>05</num>
      <num>06</num>
      <num>06</num>
   </group>
   <group>
      <num>08</num>
      <num>09</num>
      <num>10</num>
   </group>
</nums>
```

Comment: You might want to explain that condition in a bit more detail. Are you only interested in all adjacent `06` siblings or in any `06` siblings in your example?

Comment: Only adjacent 06 sibling

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to solve that using sibling recursion or, if XSLT 3.0 is available, using `xsl:iterate`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="pGroupSize" as="xs:integer" select="3"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:iterate select="*">
                <xsl:param name="group" as="element()*" select="()"/>
                <xsl:param name="last" as="element()?" select="()"/>
                <xsl:on-completion>
                    <xsl:if test="$group">
                        <group>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$group"/>
                        </group>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:on-completion>
                <xsl:if test="count($group) ge $pGroupSize and . != $last">
                    <group>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$group"/>
                    </group>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:next-iteration>
                    <xsl:with-param name="group"
                        select="if (count($group) ge $pGroupSize and . != $last)
                                then .
                                else ($group, .)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="last"
                        select="if (count($group) ge $pGroupSize and . = $last) then $last else ."/>
                </xsl:next-iteration>
            </xsl:iterate>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried applying this code to my XML. It throws an error. I am new to this. Can you show me how do I use this XSLT?

Comment: Do we need to match the "num" tag in some condition here?

Comment: The code I posted is XSLT 3.0 so you would need to use an XSLT 3.0 processor like Saxon 9 PE or EE, as available in XML IDEs like Oxygen or Stylus Studio, or as available in Altova XMLSpy with Raptor. Perhaps someone else can show you how to do it with earlier XSLT versions and the mentioned approach of "using sibling recursion", or see other solutions using that approach and try whether you can adapt them for your particular needs.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I checked in my scenario. XSLT 3.0 is not supported. Any help with XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 would be helpful. Thanks.